# CMMotionActivityManager authorization status

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I'm trying to figure out a way to handle the authorization statuses for Motion activity

Here's what I came up with so far :

```
manager = CMMotionActivityManager() 

manager.queryActivityStartingFromDate(now, toDate: now, toQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), 
                                                withHandler: { (activities: [CMMotionActivity]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in                

    if(error != nil){
        if(error!.code != Int(CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized.rawValue)){
            print("CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized")
        }else if(error!.code != Int(CMErrorMotionActivityNotEntitled.rawValue)){
            print("CMErrorMotionActivityNotEntitled")
        }else if(error!.code != Int(CMErrorMotionActivityNotAvailable.rawValue)){
            print("CMErrorMotionActivityNotAvailable")
        }
    }
})
```

#### One problem though :

When I deny the app permission to motion activity (via `settings`), I get `CMErrorMotionActivityNotEntitled`

(I believe I should be getting `CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized` instead)

Any ideas why ? or at least what's the proper way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you *are* getting `CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized`. You'll never know, with your code, because your code does not ask what code you are getting. It asks what code you are *not* getting:

```
    if(error!.code != Int(CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized.rawValue)){
        print("CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized")
    }else if(error!.code != Int(CMErrorMotionActivityNotEntitled.rawValue)){
        print("CMErrorMotionActivityNotEntitled")
    }else if(error!.code != Int(CMErrorMotionActivityNotAvailable.rawValue)){
        print("CMErrorMotionActivityNotAvailable")
    }
```

The `!=` operator means *is not*. So you are doing a series of checks about what the code *is not*. It's hard to see how you can get any useful information by asking that question. It might make more sense to ask what the code *is*, which would involve using the `==` operator.

Comment: Thank youuu ... wow I'm really shocked that I didn't notice I was using `!=` ... As you can see from the `print` I clearly was aiming for `==` ... I really don't know what happened there :(

Comment: This would have been a good situation to use a `switch` statement and then the issue would never have arisen. :)

Comment: Totally agree ... (I was trying to hack something quickly to test first and refactor later). Thank you again!